# php simplexml load remote xml returns bool(false)

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I write this php script in order to parse some XML doc.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www1.cbs.gov.il/xml/indices_heb_all.xml');
var_dump($xml);
```

When I run this script its echo "bool(false)"
What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: `simplexml_load_file` returns `false` when it fails to load the document. I think you aren't using it properly; Do you not need to `rawurlencode` the URL?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: I think your xml encoding is not utf8. It might be trying to render special characters thus failed to load it as object.

Comment: Yes your document encoding is iso-8859-8-i, which causes `parser error : Unsupported encoding iso-8859-8-i`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what would solve your problem:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(str_replace('iso-8859-8-i', 'iso-8859-8', file_get_contents('http://www1.cbs.gov.il/xml/indices_heb_all.xml')));
var_dump($xml);
```

But the encoding has to be set to UTF-8 for the text to be displayed correctly:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string(str_replace('iso-8859-8-i', 'iso-8859-8', file_get_contents('http://www1.cbs.gov.il/xml/indices_heb_all.xml')));
var_dump($xml);
?>
</body>
</html>
```