# Loading external xml link returns false

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the European Central Bank currency values like this

```
simplexml_load_file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml")
```

But this returns `false`.
I have tried with these answers [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635258/php-simplexml-load-remote-xml-returns-boolfalse), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693043/using-simplexml-to-load-remote-url/8693175)
Both doesn't work for me and can't really understand what is causing the problem.

Comment: Can you send php configuration?

Comment: This works. Make sure the [wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) is enabled.

Comment: If you do several things at the same time (in this case, download a remote resource and parse is as XML) you can never know what's failing. See also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62577 (just in case).

Answer (score -1):

```
$object = simplexml_load_file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
var_dump($object);
```

Do the php configuration changes in php.ini:
allow_url_fopen = on//if it "off"

If Above code does not work check below process:
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));//print this if it return false or 0
Do the code with CURL php.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29036236)

Comment: I think you are right!, I think it is the problem with php configuration. I provided this answer based on links user provides. Instead of this, he tried those links i thought! He can try like this :- var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))// if it returns false, he can try curl php